# admin lost sudo permission in UI?

Tags: permissions, gui

I just set up  ubuntu (11.10) and installed a lot of things. Here and there I had to edit user permission(s). Now I have to find out that all UI buttons that would evoke the sudo password window are disabled in my administrator account. When I go "Guest" everything is fine however. So I assume that I made some weird changes to the account settings of my administrator account. How can I revert this weird setting?

Thanks
Audiodroid

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You should simply revert the permission changes you have made.

As you can imagine, no one can know what you did, apart from you ;)
If you'll be more specific on what you did maybe you'll get a better answer with specific commands.

Comment: Isn't there a good handful of commands that would be good to know to handle permission in general? Isn't there a hint on which folders to look at to get a rough idea of the current permission settings? I have reinstalled the system. It is working now. But I'm sure I will run into this again.

Comment: Yes, you can see the permissions with `ls -l` and set them with `chmod`. Refer to the relative manuals for more explanations :)